# Zipkin integration with vert.x with 3.x version

Tags: vert.x

I see active work going on for vert.x integration with zipkin.
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-tracing

Will it be backward compatible with vert.x 3.8.x version? If yes, can you share tentative timelines for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the tracing SPI will not be backported to Vert.x 3.

I would recommend to check out [Migrate from Vert.x 3 to Vert.x 4](https://vertx.io/blog/from-vert-x-3-to-vert-x-4/):

> When­ever pos­si­ble, Vert.x 4 APIs have been made avail­able in
> Vert.x 3 with a dep­re­ca­tion of the old API, giv­ing the
> op­por­tu­nity to im­prove a Vert.x 3 ap­pli­ca­tion with a bet­ter
> API while al­low­ing the ap­pli­ca­tion to be ready for a Vert.x 4
> mi­gra­tion.

In other words, one of the Vert.x 4 goals was to minimize the upgrading effort.